# Get control ids from dialog box handle

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

I have a dialog box handle. I want to get a text in a input in the dialog box. I can use GetDlgItemText() function to get the text. But I have to give the control ID of the field as a parameter. So how should I find the control ID of a field (The field I need is "new password" in change password dialog).

Comment: [`GetDlgCtrlID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478(v=vs.85).aspx). Or even better, use `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, textLen + 1, (LPARAM)buffer);`

Comment: I checked it out. I have to give the handle of a control as a parameter to GetDlgCtrlID() function. If I have to get the control handle from dialog box handle I can use GetDlgItem() function which again requires the control ID as parameter. So I dont know what to do.

Comment: The reason I added "winlogon" as a tag is that change password dialog comes in that scenario. There are some ways (spy++ in VS) to find the control IDs of normal dialog boxes (save in notepad). I'm not able to use that also in this scenario

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to get a text from some editbox which is in a dialog window and the only identifier you've got is it's handle, right?

Comment: Yes. The dialog box is change password dialog box and the field I need is "new password". I mentioned it in the last line of my question.

Comment: In the good old days, malware authors knew this kind of stuff

Answer (score 2):

When you do not have the ID of the control, the only option is to enumerate all child windows of the dialog (or window) and get the types of the child windows.  You can use the `EnumChildWindows()` function to enumerate all child windows.

In your enumeration callback, you will have the `HWND` of each child control.  Get the type of the child using `GetClassName()` and see whether it is `EDIT` or not, if so then you have to decide whether that is the child control you want.

Comment: Another option is to use a `FindWindowEx()` loop instead of `EnumChildWindows()`.  That way, you can specify `EDIT` as the `lpszClass` parameter so it returns only `EDIT` child windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetWindowLongPtr() to get ID which window is active. Then Use GetDlgItem() to control that window on the same mdi window proc
Example: if you worked with multiple mdi child window. Then you control another mdi child window, for instance you want to draw text on mdi window ID 50000 from activate mdi window 50003.
Then put GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_ID). save it to int value for instance you get id is 50000 from this activate. Then you put GetDlgItem(hwnd, 50000) to get handle window id 50000, then draw some text winapi function. Then output will be text that you want to draw on mdi window id 50000 from clicked activated mdi window id 50003. Hope this can solved you problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your answer so it is understandable an easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Something this for FindDlgFileNameID:

```
var
  lp,fn_ID:integer;

function EnumChildProcess(hHwnd: HWND; var lParam: integer): boolean; stdcall;
var
  ClassName: string;
begin
  if (hHwnd=0) then
    result := false
  else begin
    SetLength(ClassName, 255);
    SetLength(ClassName,GetClassName(hHwnd,PChar(className),Length(className)));

    if Classname<>'Edit' then begin
      Result:=true;
      exit
    end;

    fn_ID:=GetDlgCtrlID(hHwnd);
    Result := false;
  end;
end;

function FindDlgFileNameID(hDialog:HWND):integer;
begin
  lp := 0; fn_ID := 0;
  EnumChildWindows(hDialog, @EnumChildProcess, integer(@lp));
  Result := fn_ID;
end;
```

Here the hDialog is the handle of parent: hDialog := GetParent(Self.Handle);

Comment: Note that the question is tagged with [visual-c++]. So, although this (Pascal?) answer may help, it would be far better if you could offer a C++ version of your code.